# Create nodes on matching, and link to existing ones

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With a graph that contains nodes with a free text property, I would like to identify nodes matching a specific regular expression, create a new annotation node and link matched nodes to the annotation one. I tried with MERGE and CREATE UNIQUE, however in both attempts several identical annotation nodes are created. I'd be very grateful if one could help me putting together the proper cypher command. Below are some code I tried:

```
MATCH (p:Paper), (a:Annotation {Keyword: 'cool'}) 
WHERE p.Title =~ ".*cool.*" 
CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[:isRelatedTo]->(a);
```

or

```
MATCH (p:Paper) WHERE p.Title =~ ".*cool.*" 
CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[:isRelatedTo]->(a:Annotation {Keyword: 'cool'});
```

or

```
MATCH (p:Paper) WHERE p.Title =~ ".*cool.*" 
MERGE (p)-[:isRelatedTo]->(a:Annotation {Keyword: 'cool'});
```

Thanks in advance, Pierre.

Comment: Eventually, the following code worked. Please feel free to comment if there is a better solution. MATCH (p:Paper), (a:Annotation {Keyword: "cool"}) WHERE p.Title =~ ".*cool.*" CREATE UNIQUE (p) -[:isRelatedTo]-> (a) return p,a;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final approach (in your comments) has these drawbacks:

1. It only works if the appropriate `Annotation` node already exists.
2. You are hardcoding the "cool" string in 2 places. I presume what you really want is to be able to do the same thing with *any* string.

EDITED

The following modified query should solve *both* of the above issues, efficiently, and also creates the `Annotation` node if necessary.

1. It uses `MERGE` to: create the `Annotation` if and only if it does not already exist.
2. It uses `CREATE UNIQUE` to create the `isRelatedTo` relationship if it does not already exist.
3. It allows you to specify a `term` parameter for the string that you want to filter for (and use as the `Keyword` for the `Annotation`). Passing the string as a parameter can make your query much faster.

> ```
> MATCH (p:Paper) WHERE p.Title =~ (".*" + {term} + ".*")
> MERGE (a:Annotation {Keyword: {term}})
> CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[:isRelatedTo]->(a)
> RETURN p, a;
> ```

Go to [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/hmr9g0) to test this (without the `term` parameter).

Comment: Indeed, I realized afterwards that it only worked on examples where the annotation node already existed. Thanks for pointing this out. In your code, how do you define {term}? I mostly use REST API to query the neo4j database, should I use "map" or something like (a:Annotation {Keyword: {term: 'cool'}}) ?

Comment: I just had a look at your console, having only one node matching 'cool' you could not have seen the duplicate Annotation node that is created. I created to addition paper nodes "life is cool" and "life is hot", hence used your query to annotate nodes matching "life", as you can see in the console, two :Annotation {Keyword: 'life'} have been created. I would have expected a single node to be created and matching paper to be linked to it.

Comment: You can also use full-text-search with Neo4j which should work better than regexps over large bodies of text, see: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/

Comment: @user3195894: Please see my updated answer. It now uses `MERGE` to avoid creating the `Annotation` more than once. I certainly agree that the behavior of CREATE UNIQUE was not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my self, above ideas were pretty close to a working solution, only missing a WITH statement.

```
MATCH (p:Paper) WHERE p.Title =~ ".*cool.*" 
MERGE (a:Annotation {Keyword: "cool"}) 
WITH a, p merge (a) <-[:isRelatedTo]- (p) 
RETURN p
```

This query creates the :Annotation node if necessary and link :Paper nodes that match the regular expression to it.

Thank you all for helping.